# Issues parsing JSON data with Swift from API

Tags: swift, swift3

I am attempting to get data from an API and bring it into swift. I have managed to connect to th API and get the data come into the console however when I attempt to parse the data I have an issue - below is the function that does the connection and should parse the data.

I am having an issue with the line:

```
let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! NSArray
```

It is producing the fatal error `SIGABRT` when running the app (the function `parseData()` is called within `viewDidLoad()`) and the console produces the following - `Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x103b7f288) to 'NSArray' (0x103b7ee28).`

```
func parseData() {

    let url = "https://api.***"

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

    let headers = [
        "user": "***",
        "auth": "***"
    ]

    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error")
        } else {
            do {

                let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! NSArray

                for eachFetchedOpportunity in fetchedData {

                    let eachOpportunity = eachFetchedOpportunity as! [String : Any]
                    let opportunity = eachOpportunity["subject"] as! String
                    let startDate = eachOpportunity["starts_at"] as! String

                    self.fetchedOpportunitys.append(Opportunity(opportunityName: opportunity, startDate: startDate))

                }

                print(self.fetchedOpportunitys)

            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()

}
```

Here is the start of the returned data (I haven't included all of the data as some of it is private and unnecessary) from the server that I have accessed through postman - I believe my problem may reside in the fact that there is a mix of Dictionaries and Arrays here and I am unaware on how to correctly parse the data if this is the case.

```
{
"opportunities": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "store_id": 1,
      "project_id": null,
      "member_id": 5,
      "billing_address_id": 5,
      "venue_id": null,
      "tax_class_id": 1,
      "subject": "***",
      "description": "",
      "number": "00000000**",
      "starts_at": "2017-05-27T08:00:00.000Z",
      "ends_at": "2017-05-27T16:00:00.000Z",
      "charge_starts_at": "2017-05-27T08:00:00.000Z",
      "charge_ends_at": "2017-05-27T16:00:00.000Z",
      "ordered_at": "2017-05-25T21:10:00.000Z",
      "quote_invalid_at": null,
      "state": 3,
...
...
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "total_row_count": 2,
    "row_count": 2,
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 12
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JSON` response is `Dictionary` not `Array` and the array you are looking for is `opportunities` that you need to get from the dictionary.

```
do {
    let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:Any]
    let opportunities = fetchedData["opportunities"] as? [[String:Any]] ?? []
    for opportunity in opportunities {     

        let subject = opportunity["subject"] as? String ?? "Default Subject"
        let startDate = opportunity["starts_at"] as? String ?? "Default Date"
        self.fetchedOpportunitys.append(Opportunity(opportunityName: subject, startDate: startDate))
    }
}
catch {
    print("Error")
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that you very much, that worked a dream. I assumed it would be something like that but as I am new to swift (literally the last couple of days) wasn't sure of syntax

Comment: @LewieClarke Welcome mate :)